# Does Process Overhead Make Linux a Better Node.js Host than Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, node.js

My understanding is that node.js is designed to scale by adding processes rather than by spawning threads in a process. In fact, from watching an [awesome introductory video by Ryan Dahl](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo_B4LTHi3I&list=WLC22E6F1B1474E337&index=1&feature=plpp_video), I get the idea that spawning threads is forbidden in node.js. I like the simplicity of this approach, but I am concerned that there might be downside when running on Windows, since [processes creation is more expensive on Windows than Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47845/why-is-creating-a-new-process-more-expensive-on-windows-than-linux).

Given modern hardware and the fact that node.js processes can be expected to be relatively long running, does process overhead still create a significant advantage for Linux when considering hosting node.js? To put it in concrete terms, if we assume an organization that is using the Windows stack only, but is planning a big move onto node.js, is there a point in considering a new OS because of this issue?

Comment: Probably yes. But you have to measure it yourself to understand if that matters to you. And going to Linux won't hurt much (but there is a learning process to follow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Node.js runs in only 1 process and doesn't spawn processes during execution.

The reason you might have gotten the impression that node uses processes to scale is because you can add a process per CPU core to enable node to take advantage of your multicore computer (you'll need a load balancer like solution for this tho). Still: you don't spawn processes on the fly. So yes, you can run node perfectly fine on Windows (or Azure) without too much of a performance hit (if any).