# c++: simple multi-threading example not faster than single thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I wrote a very simple example for multithreading in C++. How comes that multithreading and single threading have approximatly the same execution time?

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

// function adds up all number up to given number
void task(int number)
{
    int s = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<number; i++){
        s = s + i;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int n = 100000000;

    ////////////////////////////
    // single processing      //
    ////////////////////////////

    clock_t begin = clock();

    task(n);
    task(n);
    task(n);
    task(n);

    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout  << "time single-threading: "<< elapsed_secs << " sec" << endl;    

    ////////////////////////////
    // multiprocessing        //
    ////////////////////////////

    begin = clock();

    thread t1 = thread(task, n);
    thread t2 = thread(task, n);
    thread t3 = thread(task, n);
    thread t4 = thread(task, n);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();

    end = clock();
    elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "time multi-threading:  " << elapsed_secs << " sec" << endl;

}
```

for me the output of the program is

```
time single-threading: 0.755919 sec 
time multi-threading:  0.746857 sec
```

I compile my code with

```
g++ cpp_tasksize.cpp -std=c++0x -pthread
```

And I run on a 24-core-linux-machine

Comment: Isn't it simply because the compiler trivially optimizes `task` function? As in `task` is equivalent to `void task(int number) {}`.

Comment: no I don't think so. I can add  `cout << s << endl;` at the end of the `task` function. Then the sum is printed out at each execution, but still the same time for multi/single processing

Comment: Never measure time without enabling the optimizer.

Comment: @OliBlum There's a different issue with `cout`: AFAIK it is (somewhat) thread safe, meaning that only one thread at a time can flush buffer. Depending on implementation this might mean that other threads are locked. And since the loop will be optimized anyway and the thread spends most of the time on `cout`ing then you have similar times. Try using `std::this_thread::sleep_for` instead and see what happens.

Comment: There is no guarantee that multiple threads will be faster than a single thread. If you are not computationally bound, it is, in fact, likely that the overhead of multiple threads will make your application slower. And if you have to synchronize the operation of multiple threads (e.g., because you're doing something like writing to the console), it is virtually *guaranteed* that multiple threads will show no improvement over a single thread.

Comment: simple. creating the threads takes more time than to actually run the code. when you want to make your program faster by using thread, than create a thread pool when the program goes up and reuse that pool. thread creation is not cheap.

Comment: @DavidHaim Thread creation has some overhead but certainly not "_more time than to actually run the code_" in this case. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26515727/7571258) suggests it's in the microsecond range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`clock()` measures *processor time*, the time that your process spent on your cpu. In a multi-thread program it will add up time each thread spent on your cpu. Your single-thread and multi-thread implementations are reported to take about same time to run, since they are doing equal number of calculations overall.

What you need is to measure *wall clock time*. Use `chrono` library when you want to measure wall clock time.

```
#include <chrono>

int main ()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    // code section

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(end - start).count() << " ms\n";
}
```

Comment: I did not quite understand why, but with chrono it works out. Is the `clock()` function so unprecise? A little explanation would be nice

Comment: @OliBlum Edited answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: @OliBlum `clock()` is supposed to accumulate the total CPU 'ticks' consumed by the process and will (say) advance 4 times faster than a wall clock with 4 threads running. It isn't 'elapsed' time. It's consume CPU time.
Refer to: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock
NB: There's a long standing bug on MSVC (that they decline to fix) that it returns wall-clock ticks. But you already mentioned you're using Linux.