# Why starting multiple processes takes much longer on Windows than on Linux?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

See the following Python code. I am using the `Process` class from `multiprocessing` module to define Python processes. `time1` is the time before starting the processes and `time2` is the time after all the processes are started. For Ubuntu, the difference between the two times is very small, about 0.1 sec, whereas in Windows it takes about `2 sec` to start the processes. What can be done to reduce the time for Windows? Windows hardware is more high-end than Ubuntu's.

```
    p1=Process( target=process1Tasks )
    p2=Process( target=process2Tasks )
    p3=Process( target=process3Tasks )
    p4=Process( target=process4Tasks )
    p5=Process( target=process5Tasks )
    p6=Process( target=process6Tasks )
    p7=Process( target=process7Tasks )
    p8=Process( target=process8Tasks )
    p9=Process( target=process9Tasks )
    p10=Process( target=process10Tasks )
    
    time1=time.time()
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    p5.start()
    p6.start()
    p7.start()
    p8.start()
    p9.start()
    p10.start()
    time2=time.time()
    print(time2-time1)
```

Comment: Windows has a large disadvantage when it comes to spawning processes since it does not support `fork`. All data has to be serialized and handed over to the new process. Depending on the earlier code you did not show, it can be a lot.

Comment: @KlausD. What alternative can I use to start multiple processes in Windows that is efficient?

Comment: The hardware may be superior but the operating system is inferior

Comment: What you can do to make it faster depends on what your code does before the shown code (the part which has to be done for each worker process on startup).

Comment: @MichaelButscher Please explain

Comment: @MichaelButscher Each process takes data from separate dictionaries and saves it in the database. I want the data to be saved in parallel, not one by one. Also, each process takes a dictionary argument, which I have omitted here to avoid clutter.

Comment: @VaibhavSharma What the function does is irrelevant to the issue you're having. Process.start() just does what's implied by the method's name - i.e., it starts the Process which then runs asynchronously. Process.start() knows nothing about how the target is implemented. It doesn't care

Comment: @Codist I also felt the same initially; that's why I didn't include the rest of the code.

Comment: "I want the data to be saved in parallel, not one by one." This sounds like you face an I/O bottleneck and as such may be more appropriate for threading instead of multiprocessing. But similar to the question you have actually asked here, this too is impossible to tell without knowing what you are actually doing.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The question concerns the (apparently) slow process start-up time and **not** the duration / execution of those processes

Comment: @Codist Yes, did I claim otherwise? Since threads do share memory they also have a startup advantage when lots of data is shared.

Comment: @Codist To create a worker process on Windows, the Python interpreter must be loaded and some Python code executed which prepares the process to handle the actual call of the target function. After that the actual work (calling the target) can be done. Time is consumed before actual work for the preparation step and the transmission of arguments (if it contains a lot of data) for the target call. Maybe these things can be optimized.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Fair comment. If the parameters being passed to the target are large (in terms of memory requirements) then yes, serialisation would have a negative impact on timing. However, the issue exists (presumably) with the code shown in the question where no serialisation is required. It seems to be a simple fact that Windows is slow whereas *nix type systems are more efficient. For example, the code in the question executes in <0.02s on MacOS 14.0 (M2) running Python 3.12

Comment: @Codist Ubuntu is faster here not only because it is more efficient but also because Linux OS uses the `fork` option to start the process, whereas Windows uses the `spawn` option to start the process. The `fork` option is not available in Windows.

Comment: @Codist The spawn mechanism used for Windows requires that each worker process loads and initializes the same modules which the main process had loaded and calculates or somehow retrieves the same data that the main process has (at least as far as necessary for the worker to do its job). This can also need a considerable amount of time before the code can even begin to care about the target function and its arguments. The code in the question doesn't contain any complicated initialization unlike the real code, I guess.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is creating a new process more expensive on Windows than Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47845/why-is-creating-a-new-process-more-expensive-on-windows-than-linux)

Answer (score -8):

If I had the same problem, I would have used Linux because Windows is pretty graphic-based and not made for devs. The second best thing you can do is maybe do this in another low-end language like Rust, C, etc. The problem is truly hardware-specific

Comment: It has very little to do with hardware. The issue is with the operating system

Comment: @Codist Better hardware always correlates with better processing times

Comment: Not so. Run two different operating systems on the same hardware and observe the difference(s)